# Cannot connect to AWS RDS - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, amazon-rds

I am unable to connect to the SQL Server RDS I created. I was able to connect to it earlier but all of sudden I am getting error while connecting form SSMS.

**Error**

[image]

Security group rules I have:

[image]

I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work. Any idea what I am missing or what could have gone wrong all of sudden?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check RDS Security Group settings and Source IP range. Check the availability of your RDS instance. See if rebooting the RDS instance fixes the problem. Are you sitting behind corporate firewall? Are they blocking i? It really could be anything. There is not much to go with here.

Comment: Check RDS Security Group settings and Source IP range. - It has the source ip listed/allowed
Check the availability of your RDS instance. - Its public (I was able to connect till yesterday) 
See if rebooting the RDS instance fixes the problem. - I can't do as its PROD db and application is able to connect but me from SSMS.
Are you sitting behind corporate firewall? - No.
Are they blocking i? -No.

Comment: Does your IP address fall in range of allowed source IP addresses?

Comment: Yes but still not working.